# Dependency Injection with swift with dependency graph of two UIViewControllers without common parent

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory-pattern

How we can apply Dependency injection without using a Framework when we have two UIViewControllers that are very deep in the hierarchy and they both need the same dependency that holds state and those two UIViewControllers they don't have a common parent.

Example:

VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4

VC5 -> VC6 -> VC7 -> VC8

let's sat that  VC4 and VC8 they both need `UserService` that holds the current user.

Note that we want to avoid Singleton.

Is there an elegant way to handle this kind of DI situations ?

After some research I found that some mention `Abstract Factory`, `Context interfaces`, `Builder`, `strategy pattern`

But I could not find an example on how to apply that on iOS

Comment: VC1 and VC5 might not have a common parent ViewController, but the UserService could be created in AppDelegate and passed down to both.

Comment: CoreData can be a clean solution I think :)

Comment: @meggar but it's only VC4 and VC8 that needs `UserService` so passing it il all the flow to just use it only on these two children seems not optimal for me, especially when it's two or three dependencies

Comment: @FrancescoDestino how is that ? what if the data is from the remote API without local storage

Comment: _Note that we want to avoid Singleton._ - why?

Comment: In one of my application I had the problem of data to be showed offline, so I was saving JSON, took from remote API, as string in my CoreData, and parsed at the right moment

Comment: @mag_zbc easier to test, avoid global variable ...

Comment: use UserDefaults or save data to json file and parse it when you need it

Comment: You should have a router/coordinator that handles the transitions between VC's and dispenses the dependencies to each.  The view controllers should no know about each other and should not be creating each other, or else it leads to exactly the situation you have described where everything needs to know about and have references to everything else.

Comment: Are you writing UI test or Unit test?

Comment: @CodeDifferent both but the focus is on Unit testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I'll give this a try.

You said "no singleton", so I exclude that in the following, but please also see the bottom of this answer.

Josh Homann's comment is a good pointer for one solution already, but personally I have my problems with the coordinator pattern.

As Josh correctly said view controllers shouldn't know (much) about each other [1], but then how is e.g. a coordinator or any dependency passed around/accessed? There's several patterns out there that suggest how, but most have an issue that's basically going against your requirement: They more or less make the coordinator a singleton (either itself or as a property of another singleton like the `AppDelegate`). A coordinator is often times de factor a singleton, too (but not always, and it doesn't have to be).

What I tend to do is relying on **simple initialized properties or** (most often) **lazy properties** and protocol oriented programming. Let's construct an example: `UserService` shall be the protocol defining all the functionality your service needs, `MyUserService` its implementing struct. Let's assume `UserService` is a design construct that basically functions as a getter/setter system for some user related data: Access tokens (e.g. saved in the keychain), some preferences (an avatar image's URL) and the like. On initialization `MyUserService` also prepares the data (loads from the remote, for example). This is to be used in several independent screens/view controllers and is not a singleton.

Now each view controller that is interested in accessing this data has a simple property for it:

```
lazy var userService: UserService = MyUserService()
```

I keep it public because that allows me to easily mock/stub it in unit tests (if I need to do that, I can create a dummy `TestUserService` that mocks/stubs the behavior). The instantiation could also be a closure that I can easily switch out during a test if the init needs parameters. Obviously the properties don't even necessarily need to be `lazy` depending on what the objects actually do. If instantiating the object ahead of time does no harm (keep unit tests in mind, also outgoing connections), just skip the `lazy`.

**The trick** is obviously to **design `UserService` and/or `MyUserService` in a way that doesn't lead to problems when creating multiple instances of it**. However, I found that this is not really a problem 90% of the time as long as the actual data the instance is supposed to rely on is saved somewhere else, in a single point of truth, like the keychain, a core data stack, user defaults, or a remote backend.

I am aware this is kind of a cop-out answer, as in a way I am just saying describing an approach that's (at least part of) many generic patterns out there. However I found this to be the most generic and simple form to approach dependency injection in Swift. The coordinator pattern can be used orthogonal to it, but I found it to be less "Apple-like" in day to day use. It does solve a problem, but mostly the one you get it you don't properly use storyboards as they are intended (especially: just using them as "VC repos", instantiating them from there and transitioning yourself in code).

[1] Except some basic and/or minor things you can pass in a completion handler or `prepareForSegue`. That's debatable and depends on how strict you follow the coordinator or another pattern. Personally I sometimes take a shortcut here as long as it doesn't bloat up things and becomes messy. Some pop-up designs are simpler done that way.

---

As a closing remark, the phrase "Note that we want to avoid Singleton" as well as your comment regarding that under the question give me the impression you just follow that advice without properly having thought about the rationale. I know that "Singleton" is often times considered an anti-pattern, but just as often that judgement is mis-informed. A singleton can be a valid architectural concept (which you can see by the fact that it's used extensively in frameworks and libraries). The bad thing about it is just that it too often tempts developers to take shortcuts in design and abuse it as kind of an "object repository" so that they don't need to think about when and where to instantiate objects. This leads to messy-ness and the bad reputation of the pattern.

A `UserService`, depending on what that actually does in your app *might* be a good candidate for a singleton. My personal rule of thumb is: "If it manages state of something that's singular and unique, like a specific user that can only ever be in one state at a given time", I *might* go for a singleton.

Especially if you cannot design it in the way I outlined above, i.e. *if you need to have in-memory, singular state data*, a singleton is basically an easy and *proper* way to implement this. (Even then using (lazy) properties is beneficial, your view controllers then don't even need to know whether it's a singleton or not and you can still stub/mock it individually (i.e. not just the global instance).)

Comment: plus one for the response to avoiding a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

These are your requirements as I understand them:

1. VC4 and VC8 must be able to share state via a `UserService` class.
2. `UserService` must not be a singleton.
3. `UserService` must be supplied to VC4 and VC8 using dependency injection.
4. A dependency injection framework must not be used.

Within these constraints, I would suggest the following approach.

Define a `UserServiceProtocol` that has methods and/or properties for accessing and updating the state. For example:

```
protocol UserServiceProtocol {
    func login(user: String, password: String) -> Bool
    func logout()
    var loggedInUser: User? //where User is some model you define
}
```

Define a `UserService` class that implements the protocol and stores its state somewhere.

If the state only needs to last as long as the app is running, you could store the state in a particular *instance*, but this *instance* would have to be shared between VC4 and VC8.

In this case, I would recommend creating and holding the instance in `AppDelegate` and passing it through the chain of VCs.

If the state needs to persist between launches of the app, or if you don't want to pass an instance through the chain of VCs, you could store the state in user defaults, Core Data, Realm, or any number of places external to the class itself.

In that case, you could create the `UserService` in VC3 and VC7 and pass it in to VC4 and VC8. VC4 and VC8 would have `var userService: UserServiceProtocol?`. The `UserService` would need to restore its state from the external source. This way even though VC4 and VC8 have different instances of the object, the state would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe there's a wrong assumption in your question.

You define your VC'c hierarchy as such:

> Example:
>
> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4
>
> VC5 -> VC6 -> VC7 -> VC8

However, on iOS (unless you're using some very strange hacks) there's always going to be a common parent at some point, like a navigation controller, tab bar controller, master-detail controller or page view controller.

So I assume that a correct scheme could look, for example, like this:

> Tab Bar Controller 1 -> Navigation Controller 1 -> VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4
>
> Tab Bar Controller 1 -> Navigation Controller 2 -> VC5 -> VC6 -> VC7 -> VC8

I believe looking at it like this makes it easy to answer your question.

Now if you're asking for an opinion what's the best way to handle DI on iOS, I'd say there's no such thing as the best way. However I personally like to stick to the rule that objects should not be responsible for their own creation/initialization. So things like

```
private lazy var service: SomeService = SomeService()
```

are out of question. I'd prefer an init that requires `SomeService` instance or at least (easy for ViewControllers):

```
var service: SomeService!
```

That way you pass the responsibility of fetching the right models/services etc up to the creator of the instance, meanwhile you can implement your logic with a simple but important assumption that you have everything you need to have (or you make your class fail early (for example by using force unwrapping), which is actually good during development).

Now, how you fetch these models - is it by initialising them, passing them around, having a singleton, using providers, containers, coordinators etc - it's entirely up to you and also should depend on factors like the complexity of the project, client demands, whatever tools you're using - so generally, whatever works is fine, as long as you stick to good OOP practices.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach I've used on a few projects that may help you.

1. Create all your view controllers via factory methods in a ViewControllerFactory.
2. The ViewControllerFactory has its own UserService object.
3. Pass the ViewControllerFactory's UserService object to those view controllers that need it.

A modest example here:

```
struct ViewControllerFactory {

private let userService: UserServiceProtocol

init(userService: UserServiceProtocol) {
    self.userService = userService
}

// This VC needs the user service
func makeVC4() -> VC4 {
    let vc4 = VC4(userService: userService)
    return vc4
}

// This VC does not
func makeVC5() -> VC5 {
    let vc5 = VC5()
}

// This VC also needs the user service
func makeVC8() -> VC8 {
    let vc8 = VC8(userService: userService)
    return vc8
}
}
```

The ViewControllerFactory object can be instantiated and stored in AppDelegate.

That's the basics. In addition, I'd also look at the following (see also the other answers that have made some good suggestions here):

1. Create a UserServiceProtocol that UserService conforms to. This makes it easy to create mock objects for testing.
2. Look into the Coordinator pattern to handle navigation logic.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the coordinator/router design pattern is most suited for injecting dependences and handling app navigation. Have a look at this post, it helped me a lot https://medium.com/@dkw5877/flow-coordinators-333ed64f3dd

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve this and uploaded an example architecture here: https://github.com/ivanovi/DI-demo

To make it more clear, I simplified the implementation using three VCs, but the solution will work with any kind of depth. The view controllers chain is as follows:

Master -> Detail -> MoreDetail(where the dependency is injected)

The proposed architecture has four building blocks:

- Coordinator Repository: Contains all coordinators and the shared states. Injects the required dependencies.
- ViewController Coordinator: Executes the navigation to the next ViewController. The coordinator holds a factory that produces the needed next instance of a VC.
- ViewController factory: Responsible for initialising and configuring a specific ViewController. It is normally owned by a coordinator and injected by the CoordinatorRepository into the Coordinator.
- The ViewController: The ViewController to be presented on the screen.

N.b.: In the example I return the newly created VC instance just to produce the example - i.e. in real life implementation returning the VC is not needed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
let viewController = CustomViewController()
viewController.data = NSObject() //some data object
navigationController.show(viewController, sender: self)


import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appCoordinator:AppCoordinator?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController()
        appCoordinator = AppCoordinator(with: window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController)
        appCoordinator?.start()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```